# Alternatives to Xampp for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make a C# student management system and I don`t know if I need to use Xampp or I can use something else. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: No, you don't need Apache to or PHP to run C# applications. The C# ecosystem has its own web servers and page templating framework  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet though you could create a Apache/PHP site with a C# API server if that's closer to your skill set.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is for deploying PHP or Perl applications. C# is most typically run by IIS, both locally as well as on a server.